# Jquery table search with pagination

Tags: jquery, tablesorter, quick-search

I am using **quicksearch** and **tablesorter.pager** Jquery plugins on a table of data.

I can get quicksearch to filter results on a single page, not all the data across all pages.

I wondered if anyone else had solved this problem using these or any other jQuery plugins.

Comment: have we answered your question?  If so, please accept one of the answers...thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is far, far easier with [Datatables](http://www.datatables.net), which offers the sorting and filtering out of the box with no need for additional plugins.  Results can be paged and filtered client side or handled via ajax on the server side if you get tables with too much data in them to operate in an effective manner (slow loading).

The result is faster, easier, and also supports ThemeRoller which makes the presentation just that much better for the user.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, will try it if I run into loading problems.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved with tabelsorter.filter plugin.

This took several attempts to get working as it required a modified version of tablesorter (for cacheing)

See https://github.com/jbritten/jquery-tablesorter-filter.